# How to print string method, idk how to phrase this sorry

Tags: java, methods

```
package com.example.test1;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class class1{
    public static String methodOne(String name){
        String studentName = name + " is his name";
        return (studentName);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        methodOne("John");
    }

}
```

How can I get this method to print out name + " is his name"? It shows nothing when I run this. I also can't add a System.out.println in the String studentName. I'm new to all of this sorry. EDIT: I want to somehow input the print function into the method and not type out System.out.println to print out methodOne, is it possible?

Comment: by adding a print statement. You can add the println in the main method

Comment: "I also can't add a System.out.println in the String studentName. " - I'm not sure what you've tried but you probably have a misconception here and thus I suggest you grab a Java tutorial and work through that. To print the string you could do the following: `System.out.println(studentName);` in `methodOne()` or `String s = methodOne("John"); System.out.println(s);` in `main()`.

Comment: Replace `methodOne("John");` with `System.out.println(methodOne("John"));`. Alternatively, you can do like, `String s = methodOne("John"); System.out.println(s);`. The point is, you have to use the return value of `methodOne` inside `System.out.println`.

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.example.test1;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class class1{
    public static String methodOne(String name){
        String studentName = name + " is his name";
        return (studentName);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(methodOne("John")); // Print string in this console
    }

}
```

Comment: What did you fix?

Comment: Added System.out.println which prints to the console

Answer (score 0):

The function of returns a value that is string, so when you call her like that :

```
methodOne("John");
```

You didn't use the string value, you didn't say print it or anything.

You can use the returned value like this:

```
   package com.example.test1;

    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class class1{
        public static String methodOne(String name){
            String studentName = name + " is his name";
            return (studentName);
        }


        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String nameStudent = methodOne("John"); // Saves the returned value in a variable
            System.out.println(nameStudent ); // Prints the returned value stored in the variable
        }

    }
```

You can also print straight without storing a variable, as they say here already.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to somehow input the print function into the method.

There are two ways I could interpret it.

You could just mean that you want print within the `methodOne` method.  That is easy:

```
public static String methodOne(String name){
    String studentName = name + " is his name";
    System.out.println(studentName);
    return studentName;
}
```

Comments:

1. If you are going to do it this way, there isn't an obvious reason why `methodOne` needs to return anything.  You could declare it as a `void` method.
2. Doing this is probably bad design.  Generally speaking, a method should do one thing.  (The design principle is Separation of Concerns (SoC).)  But this modified method is doing two things.  It is forming the string, and it is printing it.  And since it is printing it to a specific place (standard output), it's utility is limited.  (What if I wanted to create that string without printing it?  What if I wanted to print it to a different stream?)

---

The second interpretation is that you **literally** want to pass the `println` method to the `methodOne` method ... so that it can call it.  This is how you could do it:

```
public static String methodOne(String name,
                               java.util.function.Consumer<String> fn){
    String studentName = name + " is his name";
    fn(studentName);
    return studentName;
}
```

and call it like this

```
methodOne("Fred", System.out::println);
```